# how can I specify the length/width of the border under li

Tags: html, css, hover, border

I want a border under the li, but the border is taking up the full width. Is there a way to add a border bottom which doesn't takes the full width of li

```css
.aboutusNav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: black
}

.aboutusNav {
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}

.aboutusNav:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #EB644C;

}
```

```html
 <ul>
 <li class="aboutusNav"><a>AboutUs</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what's on the image exactly do you mean an animation on hover?

Comment: Please also review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MoussaBistami, I want the border in center with small width so It doesn't take the full width of li. Yes animation would be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try use a pseudo element `::before` or `::after` as the border, style it as needed and add a transition.

[More about pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

This example uses `::before` just so that if `::after` is also added later for another effect, its natural position is stacked on top of `::before`. But it seems that using either `::before` or `::after` would not make a significant difference in this use case alone.

Example:

```css
.aboutusNav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: black;
}

.aboutusNav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.aboutusNav::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -3px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #eb644c;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.aboutusNav:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(0.5);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="aboutusNav"><a>AboutUs</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you please explain why you used the before